# i cannot modify my android project's java path

Tags: android, eclipse, import, gps, r.java-file

I transferred an Android project from another machine. I want to learn, how can I do correctly edit my Android project's /Gen folder on Java files.

First I import my existing codes and select `buildautomaticly` mode.

"properties selected googleapis 2.2. API 8" and "not used in library .."

When I try to fix error I create an id on `r.java`. But if `buildautomaticly` mode is on, it doesn't work - my changes are refreshed, and I lose my ids layout and each other again.

If I try to unselect `buildautomaticly` mode I don't get an error, but it doesn't work on debug and simulation of gps.

I tried to clean every time, but that didn't help.

[PLS LOOKUP my android project's capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spgy0.jpg)

Comment: gen is automatically generated inside your project.Remove any error in xml and your R.java will build automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to recognize which API level your project is in need, by selecting different one by one.
And do not worry about the R class id's, because they always generated by itself whenever yu build your project. Its good if you build yourself.
If R class ids are not generating then restart your eclipse ID , and allow the SDk to load again.
May be these steps can solve out your problem

Comment: i tried something about the modify my project. firstly if i use the old version eclipse(indigo) and sdk (so: main machine's version ) there's not any error getting. and if i used one of them;on other machine, i'm getting same error. and while using the old version eclipse(indigo) and SDK plugins i warned by eclipse for upgrade ; and if i upgrade it, getting same errror.you think is this about the libraries?

Answer (score -1):

dont modify R.java. probably one of libraries you are using not installed to new machine. try to configure it with Android Sdk manager.